# Clickable boxes in nav rather than text in the box - display-block doesn't work

Tags: html, css, nav

I'm trying to get my navigation items to be clickable blocks rather than just the text inside the block but I can't get it to work. I've added a `display-block` against my `<a>` tag but it's having no effect. What am I missing?

```
nav li {
    float: left;
    margin: 0 1em 0 1em;
    list-style-type: none;
    background-color: lightblue;
    border-radius: 10%;
    padding: .7em;
}

nav a { 
    color: #6a6a6a;
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
}

nav ul {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

nav {
    display: inline-block;
}

<nav>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Gallery</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Calendar</a></li>
    </ul>   
</nav>
```

Comment: You need to apply the padding to the links of course, and not the list items.

Comment: Move padding: .7em; to nav a

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to apply the padding to the `<a>` tags themselves, not the `<li>`s